# printing from an array php

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to print an integer from an array in php.

I am attempting a question on the coding site [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference).

The pre-supplied function takes in a string input and manipulates it into an array like so:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$a = array();
for($a_i = 0; $a_i < $n; $a_i++) {
   $a_temp = fgets($handle);
   $a[] = explode(" ",$a_temp);
  array_walk($a[$a_i],'intval');
}

echo $a[0];

?>
```

However running

```
echo $a[0]
```

results the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in solution.php on line 12
```

and outputs:

```
Array
```

I understand that this is because I am trying to manipulate the array as a string but I am not sure how else one could print out indexed values. Ideally I would like to use a c-type for loop:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++) {
    echo $a[$x];
}
```

Using print_r($a[0]) gives the following output:

[image: hackerrank output]

Comment: You can use print_r() or var_dump() to see what's the value of an array

Comment: What would you *expect/like* the output to be?

Comment: the first integer in the array

Comment: So `echo $a[0][0]`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing an array use `print_r()`.

Example: `print_r($a[0])`;

`$a[0]` is an array in this scope and not a string.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to print just the integer at index 0? I've added an image of the output given by print_r($a[0])

Comment: You have a multidimensional array. To can use `echo $a[0][0]`, which would print `11` in your case.`echo $a[0][1]` would print `2`.

Comment: Yes that works-thanks. Might be out of scope, but what is the benefit of creating such an array?